# View local database while running the app on device

Tags: ios, swift

When I run the app on simulator, then I can view the data stored in coredata in the firefox SQLiteManager. All I need to do to view the database is get the path and go to the .sqlite file at that path.

But how do I view the data I have stored via coredata while running the app on an actual device..?

Comment: In Xcode Devices window you can copy the app sandbox to your computer.

Comment: I'm sorry @matt. What does app sandbox mean actually..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @matt said you can download the app sandbox to your computer and then you can view the SQL like you did:

Do the following:

1. in XCode select `Window` in the menu bar and select -> `Devices And Simulators`
2. Locate the device for which you want sandbox to be downloaded (you have a list of devices on the left)
3. Find your app in `Installed apps` section and select the `Gear` icon and select `Download Container`
4. Specify the location then open the folder of your app sandbox and find the sql database...

[image: DownloadContainer]

Comment: sorry for the late response @Ladislav. But I've managed to view the db in sqlite manager. But once I change the data, I'm not able to get the updated results. Pressing the refresh button gives no results..

Comment: You have an option there to replace container, so just save your data and select that same folder and it will be replaced

Comment: Try and if it works you can mark the answer as answered by clicking on the green checkmark below next to point count in my answer.